# How to detect dark theme in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

`Ubuntu 20.04` has introduced Dark theme in its settings.

Is it possible to detect (programmatically) that it is turned on?

I'm using `C++` and `Qt` in my app.

Answers for another Linux distors are appreciated as well.